# CCNET returns incorrect CCNetLabel value at first time build with filelabeller and selectparameter

Tags: config, cruisecontrol.net

I am with CCNET 1.6.7981.1 at the moment, and am having this issue where CCNetLabel returns the first line from a specified file via  instead of a user-specified value from  at its first time building. However for the 2nd time and onwards, it returns user-specified value correctly.

On the other side of this coin, is there a way to assign a dynamic value $(BuildVersion)/$[BuildVersion] to the pre-defined property $CCNetLabel?

Much appreciated if I can pick your brain on this one. See below the project config that produces this issue.

```
<cb:define name="parameters_cvo_select">
    <parameters>
        <selectParameter>
          <name>BuildVersion</name>
          <display>Choose an existing build to deploy</display>
          <description>Select an exsiting build to deploy:</description>
          <sourceFile>_VersionList.number</sourceFile>
          <required>true</required>
        </selectParameter>
    </parameters>
</cb:define>

<cb:define name="labeller_cvo_file">
    <labeller type="fileLabeller">
        <labelFilePath>_postfix.number</labelFilePath>
        <prefix>_$[BuildVersion]</prefix>
        <allowDuplicateSubsequentLabels>true</allowDuplicateSubsequentLabels>     
    </labeller> 
</cb:define>


<project    name="MyProj_1"
                queue="Q2"
                queuePriority="1">                       
    <cb:parameters_cvo_select/>
    <cb:labeller_cvo_file/> 
    <tasks>     
        <parallel>
          <tasks>           
          </tasks>
        </parallel>
    </tasks>
    <cb:security_adminOnly />       
    <publishers>
        <modificationHistory onlyLogWhenChangesFound="true" />
      <xmllogger />
     <cb:email_always_adminOnly />
    </publishers>
    <externalLinks>
    </externalLinks>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does ring a bell, there are/were other items related to initial builds.
I'll try to look at this, it *should* be easy to fix : there is an isInitial property on integrationRequest, and you provided a nice scenario to simulate it.
I made an issue for it, so you can follow it there :
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/issues/301

Comment: Thanks Ruben. It'd be great to actually allow to assign a dynamic value, e.g $(BuildVersion) from a <selectParameter> to the pre-defined property $CCNetLabel. I rkn the way I do it at the moment is a work-around by assigning $(BuildVersion) to <prefix> - surely it's not designed this way.

In this particular scenario I cannot use <fileLabeller> to update $CCNetLabel because the version number stored in the file will only be updated when a script is run where as $CCNetLabel is defined BEFORE the first <pre-build> task according to the documentation.